# Height of fluid and pressure

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, capillary-action

[image]
It’s a well known fact that pressure at bottom of the contain depends on height of the fluid column above it.

If I add a ultra thin capillary tube as a **fifth tube**, then height of the water column rises due to adhesive force of water.

1.What happens to pressure at the bottom of the container?
According to me it should increase

2.Also what about height of fluid, will it remain same in all the five tubes?

Answer (score 5):

No, it will not increase, because the adhesive force eliminates the increased gravitational force of water in the column.

Comment: How could I have missed that , anyways could please add more details about how to quantify the scenario.

Comment: @Chemist The additional information is obtained by a force balance on the column of water. Include the pressure force (downward), the surface tension force (upward for wetting contact angles and downward for non-wetting), and gravity force. The net force at the bottom is the same regardless of the contact angle.

Comment: Should I consider whole of the column of liquid or just the upper part?